# Elastic search query all fields with name

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have the following documents:

```
{
    "name" : "abc",
    "something" : {
        "url" : "asd"
    }
}

{
    "name" : "abc",
    "something-else" : {
        "url" : "asd"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create a query which would ask for all documents with any field `url = asd`?

Comment: Your description is not that detailed. What is the mapping of the document? Any `url` should be equal to `asd` or both urls should be equal to `asd`? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I've updated my question

Comment: You can use a [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting): `{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "whatever",
      "fields": ["*.url"]
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "asd",
      "fields": ["*.url"]
    }
  }
}
```

or with `query_string`:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["*.url"],
      "query": "asd"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I use this in a query string?

Comment: I told you didn't provide the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `should` filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
           "should" : [
             { "term": { "something.url": "asd" }},
             { "term": { "something-else.url": "asd" }}
           ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that there are two `url` fields in his sample document.

Comment: that doesn't match documents with something-else.url

Comment: So as I understand it there is no way to match all fields with the name url? I need to specify each one?